# Active Directory and Proxy issues

Tags: proxy, active-directory

I am faced by the strangest issue ever.
We have a proxy server and had to change its IP once we changed, it some users were not able to browse some sites. The profiles did not Change but requests don't reach the proxy.
On other PC with new profile some users can browse and all is ok.